# I need to get the extract the zip code from the result of this loop.

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

What can I do to only get the zipcode, and not the whole address? right now it shows a whole address which contains a zipcode, is there a way of extracting the zipcode?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as py
from tabulate import tabulate
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

my_data = pd.read_csv('dt/TrafficCounts_OpenData_wm.csv')


geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_application")
sub_set = my_data[["POINT_Y","POINT_X"]]
count = 0
for y in sub_set.itertuples() :
    mypoint = str(y[1]) + ' ,' + str(y[2])
    print(mypoint)
    location = geolocator.reverse(mypoint)
    print(location)
    if count == 5 : break
    count +=1
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the output you get?

Comment: 29.607416999999998 ,-95.114007
Pinebrook KinderCare, 4422, Clear Lake City Boulevard, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77059, USA
29.74770501 ,-95.39656199
2345, Commonwealth Street, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77006, USA
29.707028 ,-95.59624701
Hastings Ninth Grade Center, 6750, Cook Road, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77072, USA
29.59038673 ,-95.47975719
6333, Court Road, Houston, Fort Bend County, Texas, 77053, USA
29.67591366 ,-95.32867835
7084, Crestmont Street, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77033, USA

Comment: do you want to extract zipcode from this string ?`'29.607416999999998 ,-95.114007 Pinebrook KinderCare, 4422, Clear Lake City Boulevard, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77059, USA 29.74770501 ,-95.39656199 2345, Commonwealth Street, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77006, USA 29.707028 ,-95.59624701 Hastings Ninth Grade Center, 6750, Cook Road, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77072, USA 29.59038673 ,-95.47975719 6333, Court Road, Houston, Fort Bend County, Texas, 77053, USA 29.67591366 ,-95.32867835 7084, Crestmont Street, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77033, USA '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since zip codes are always the last 5 digits or 5 plus 4 digits in an address, you can use the following regex to extract the zip code from the address stored in your `location` variable:

```
import re
zipcode = re.search(r'\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?=\D*$)', location).group()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, could you explain me the sintax? i am new with python

Comment: You're welcome. Which specific syntax do you need explanations on? Is it regular expression, or is it the usage of `re.search`?

Comment: re.search(r'\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?(?=\D*$)' Could you explain this deeply? I am trying to look for it on the regex api, but did not find. Thanks.

Comment: It would be worth your time to understand the regex syntax by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). But basically what I'm doing here is simply to match 5 digits (`\d{5}`), optionally followed by another 4 digits preceded by a dash (`(?:-\d{4})?`), while requiring that the match has to be followed by zero or more non-digit characters until the end of the string (`(?=\D*$)`), which really means to prohibit another number to follow the zip code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were more than helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Comment: sure, thanks. now it is working pretty fine
My problem now is that I want to create a new column in that df with the new zipcode values, yet whenever I created it only shows the last value.
I will put an example of the result in the next comment.

Comment: OBJECTID                            SEGMENT  ...      POINT_Y    ZIP
0            1          E CITY LIMIT TO EL DORADO  ...    29.607417  61957
1            2                WAUGH TO WESTHEIMER  ...    29.747705  61957
2            3          BELLAIRE TO ALIEF CLODINE  ...    29.707028  61957
3            4         S POST OAK TO CHIMNEY ROCK  ...    29.590387  61957
4            5             SOUTH LOOP TO BELLFORT  ...    29.675914  61957
5            6                FULTON TO IRVINGTON  ...    29.828525  61957

Comment: Do you mean you have several addresses in one string? The regex in my answer is designed to work with one address per string.

Comment: No, the regex works pretty fine. It is extracting the zip code from all the addresses I have. However, I need to put those zips in a new column in the dataset I am getting the addresses from but whenever I try to print that new column it only shows the last zip code from that list of addresses. How can I get all the zip codes in a different column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know regex I think you can do something like this but you should learn about them they will give you more robust behavior.

```
data ='''29.607416999999998 ,-95.114007 Pinebrook KinderCare, 4422,Clear Lake City Boulevard, Houston, Harris County, Texas,77059,USA
29.74770501 ,-95.39656199 2345, Commonwealth Street, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77006, USA
29.707028 ,-95.59624701 Hastings Ninth Grade Center, 6750, Cook Road, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77072, USA 
29.59038673 ,-95.47975719 6333, Court Road, Houston, Fort Bend County, Texas, 77053, USA
29.67591366 ,-95.32867835 7084, Crestmont Street, Houston, Harris County, Texas, 77033, USA'''

dl = data.split('USA')
# print(dl)
```

```
# 1)

zip_code_lst = []
for addrs in dl:
    zip_found = addrs.rstrip(', ')[-5:] # --> 77006,whitspace --> 77006
    if len(zip_found) == 5:
        zip_code_lst.append(zip_found)

print(zip_code_lst) # ['77059', '77006', '77072', '77053', '77033']
```

```
# 2)

zip_code_lst_comp =  [ addrs.rstrip(', ')[-5:] for addrs in dl ]

print(zip_code_lst_comp) # ['77059', '77006', '77072', '77053', '77033', '']
```